# Azure table storage Node JS function app return response empty

Tags: node.js, api, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

I'm writing a Azure function app to query entities,
I'm getting the response in the callback but when result body is set with response it still returns empty,

I am not able to return the entities as response because the process thread finishes before the response is set ,I'm not sure how to solve this I've tried setInterval but no luck

below is the code

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    var storage = require('azure-storage')
    var storageClient = storage.createTableService(process.env.connectionString)
    var storageTableQuery = storage.TableQuery
    var query = new storageTableQuery().top(1).where('Mobile eq \'' + context.req.query.mobile + '\'')
    storageClient.queryEntities("Customers", query, null, function (error, result) {
        if (error) {
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: error               
            }
        }
        else {
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: result.entries,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if there's data matching your query?

Comment: yes there is data when debugging

Comment: Can you check if you're getting `continuationToken` in `result`?

Comment: `continuationToken` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding the issue, please refer to the following code

```
const azure = require("azure-storage");
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  const tableSvc = azure.createTableService(AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING);
  const tableQuery = new azure.TableQuery()
    .top(1)
    .where("PartitionKey eq ?", "Jack");
  try {
    const result = await queryEntitiesSegmented(
      tableSvc,
      "test",
      tableQuery,
      null
    );
    context.res = {
      status: 200,
      body: result.entries,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    context.res = {
      status: 200,
      body: error,
    };
  }


async function queryEntitiesSegmented(
  tableSvc,
  table,
  tableQuery,
  continuationToken
) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    tableSvc.queryEntities(
      table,
      tableQuery,
      continuationToken,
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

[image]
[image]